# React setState and then check for the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's the problem on this function? Why I can't check for a variable state after set a value?

```js
const updateHandler = () => {
  this.setState({ logged: true })
  if (this.state.logged) {
    this.setState({ showDialog: true })
  }
}
```

Comment: You should do both changes in the same `setState`. I see really no reason not to since you're explicitly setting `logged` to true just before.

Answer (score 2):

this.setState is async, so it is not guaranteed that you have the new state in the next line. To do that you need to write the code as a callback to setState:

```
    this.setState({
     logged: true
    }, () => {
     if (this.state.logged){ 
      this.setState({ showDialog: true }) 
    } 
  })
```

But there is no reason to use it, because in that case logged will always be true.

A good reason to use it is when you have a complicated shouldComponentUpdate. In that case it is useful to see what you have after setting the state

Comment: While this is working, it's a code smell. `logged` is set to true just above, so there's no reason for the condition at all. `this.setState({ logged: true, showDialog: true })`

Comment: I agree, will edit my answer